# change the integral order $\int_{2}^{\sqrt 12} \int_{1}^{x^2/4}dy\, dx$ how do we change order here?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{2}^{\sqrt {12}} \int_{1}^{\frac{x^2}{4}}dy dx$$

All the tutorials with order change are usually very simple so i wonder how do we solve order change like this

Comment: Is $\chi$ the same as $x$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng  yes of course. i just have greek keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the region out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First draw a picture of the set

$$A=\{(x,y): x \in [2, \sqrt{12}], 1 \le y \le x^2/4\}.$$

Then we have

$$A=\{(x,y): y \in [1,3], 2 \sqrt{y} \le x \le \sqrt{12}\}.$$

This gives

$$\int_{2}^{\sqrt 12} \int_{1}^{x^2/4}dy dx= \int_1^3 \int_{2 \sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{12}}dx dy.$$

Comment: From where do we get the 2sqrt(y) ?

Comment: For $y \ge 1$ we have $y=x^2/4 \iff 4y=x^2 \iff 2 \sqrt{y}=x.$